# Power supply for multiple solenoids

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, solenoid

I'm currently looking to power 10 solenoids:
rated (nominal) at 24VDC, 400mA, 10mm stroke, 25N. (JF-1040 no datasheet unfortunately)

I will be powering with a voltage higher, (giving me a range to work with PWM from arduino) e.g. 48V to get a bigger force, then holding at a much lower duty cycle 1/10 seconds later. (Just need the initial higher force)

As I don't really have a ton of experience I was a bit stumped by the current requirements and how to deal with it using a standard power supply. 
By measuring the resistance, the solenoid is 30.6 ohm.
[image: Solenoid Driver circuit]

Will the use of capacitors in the circuit be sufficient and appropriate? since the spike in current will only be for 1/10 second.
If yes, how would I go about implementing this?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You say the solenoids are rated for 400 mA at 24 V.  That implies 60 Ohms, yet you measure half that.  Something isn't right.

Comment: Yeah, I had noticed that. https://www.amazon.co.uk/sourcingmap%C2%AE-Frame-Solenoid-Electromagnet-Actuator/dp/B00RV6HWH0/ref=pd_day0_23_6?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=6K9FHR9N5R2SQJE697X2 Since the solenoids are from china and come with no datasheet I could find, it is probably rated for 12V instead. In that case, I will have to lower the overall voltage from the power supply. What's a good voltage for cheap power supplies?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty impossible to be sure without testing, but here's some pointers:

- Generally speaking, what you're doing is okay, though not ideal.
- A solenoid's pulling power is proportional to the current flowing in it, not the voltage across it. Eventually more voltage leads to more current, but they are not constantly proportional.
- The solenoid is more inductive than resistive, so that 30 ohm you measure is only the steady state resistance - the effective resistance will be much high when you first switch it on, so it may take some time for the current to rise.
- Same goes when you switch off (during PWM) - the current will fall relatively slowly (circling through the diode).
- Since you don't have direct control over the current, you'll waste some power as the current sawtooths up and down during the PWM cycle. The bottom of the sawtooth must be high enough to maintain enough pulling power and everything above that is superfluous, so the smaller the cycles the better.
- Adding capacitance to the load wont help because the solenoid's inductance will limit the current rise regardless.

So basically your concept is sufficient, if not ideal. When you first switch the MOSFET on, current will rise in the solenoid until enough is flowing to activate it (the pick-up value). You can then turn the MOSFET off to allow the current to fall. You need to turn the MOSFET back on before the current falls to the drop-out value. At that point you can cycle the MOSFET on and off to get the current as steady as possible.

To find the pick-up and drop-out points will take some experimentation, and there's likely to be a lot of chattering and noise and variation to contend with.

More sophisticated relay drivers force current in and out of the solenoid more dramatically (using stored current in an inductor or reverse supplies for example) and even measure the effective impedance of the coil to determine pick-up and drop-out points. But with a bit of experimentation you'll be able to get most of the way there without that extra complexity.